# sed, awk regex to replace a string

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I am working on a CSV file like this

`"EF", "12345", "Test, String", "Xyz"` and I need output as

```
"EF", "12345", "Test$$$ String", "Xyz"
```

basically I need to replace the comma with $$$

Comment: Iam sorting a huge CSV file (~4GB) based on certain columns. The CSV file is comma separated.I intend to use unix `sort` which is faster, however I have some rows which contain comma(,)in the row values.How do I sort in such case as the number of columns will increase if (,) is used as delimiter.

Example:
Here I want to sort based on 2 and and 4th column, but if I use (,) as delimiter i will get total 5 columns in 1st row and 4 columns in second row that would spoil the sorting. 

    "wert","DGC","Xyt, temp","3456"
    "wert","ABC","ppp","1234"

Comment: eliminate a whole class of problems from your data processing and start exporting your data with the `|` character as delimiter. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but replacing the delimiter is something which is  not in my control, so Iam looking for alternatives

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

`, ([^"])`

And replace by:

`$$$ $1`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fC0xX8/3)

---

Or even this:

`([^"]),`

And replace by:

`$1$$$`

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/fC0xX8/2)

Comment: my sed and awk don't support lookahead/behind. yours does?

Comment: Thank you, but the regex fails for "EF", "12345", ",Test String", "Xyz" Can this case also be handled

Comment: @jsphdnl. And what is the new expected result? Can you update the question?

Comment: Failed if `"field", ", ", ", ", "field"` occur

Answer (score 3):

You can use gnu-awk for this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=", "; FPAT="\"[^\"]+\""} {sub(/,/, "$$$", $3)} 1' file
"EF", "12345", "Test$$$ String", "Xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed ':a
     s/^\(\([[:blank:]]*"[^"]*",\)*[[:blank:]]*"[^",]*\),/\1\$\$\$/
     t a
     ' YourFile
```

- posix version
- use recursive remove of `;` inside string delimited by `"` (so not the fastest)
- assuming there is no escaped `"` inside string (if the case, need to adapt a bit)

Answer (score 0):

It works with sub as well.

awk '{sub(/Test,/,"Test$$$")}1' file
"EF", "12345", "Test$$$ String", "Xyz"